# C++ Keyboard Hook - Exit program but also prevent key from being processed elsewhere

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a hook that must exit the program when a set key is pressed and also not allow that input to be processed elsewhere.  Normally you'd return a non-zero input inside the hook function so that the input is not used elsewhere however since I am using exit(0) I am unable to stop the keyboard input from interfering with other applications that may be behind the program.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can block the input?

Comment: Never tried it but how about passing the call to `exit()` as an [APC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951(v=vs.85).aspx) to the hook functions calling thread? If the calling thread goes into an alertable wait state after handling all hook callbacks `exit` should be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your hook function process the hook normally (with 'consumed' flag).
The only thing that you need to do is not to call `exit(0)` which is synchronous function but call `PostQuitMessage(0)`.

`PostQuitMessage(0)` will *post* WM_QUIT message that will be processed *after* the keyboard event will be handled.

Comment: Yes, this is an excellent answer.  I found DestroyWindow(0) and started using that but this is a far better solution to my problem.  Thanks for your input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by calling DestroyWindow(hWnd) instead of using exit and then using return 1 afterwards.